# How to make contextmenu appear when right-clicking on an empty space inside a Viewport3D? (C# WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, viewport3d

I've been trying to find a solution but can't. Right now my context menu appears only when I right-click on a 3d object withing the `Viewprot3D`. Does anyone know a solution?

```
   <Viewport3D Name="Scene" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Margin="0,1,0,-1" Grid.RowSpan="2" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ModellingMenu}" MouseDown="Scene_MouseDown">
<!-- Your 3D content goes here -->
```

I had an idea that there could be a control over it that will be click-through, but `Viewport3D` doesn't support the property `IsHitTestVisible`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the `Viewport3D` element in a painted `Panel` and show the `ContextMenu` on this one:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ModellingMenu}" MouseDown="Scene_MouseDown">
    <Viewport3D ... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yeah that actually worked. I just now have to fidn  way to fit it poeprly inside my app.